# What input type to use for image in external url?

Tags: html

I know that if I want to have a html field that let's the user upload a local file I can use

```
<input type="file"></input>
```

However, let's say I am guaranteed that all images will be at a valid absolute URL to an image. How do I let the user specify that? What input type do I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use:

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

HTML5 has url input types:

```
<input type="url"></input>
```

Consult the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input) on inputs for more inforation.

Comment: `<input type="url">` can safely be used, since it degrades to `<input type="text">` on non-conforming browsers. The end tag `</input>` should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is just specifying a URL at which you can find the image, then all they're really entering is text.  There's no `input` element that's specific for a URL.

```
<input type="text" />
```

What you *do* with that text is another story entirely.  There's no way for the HTML to validate that it's a URL for an image, a valid URL, etc.  That's all stuff you'd have to do in code.